# How can I remove objects from a list based on a property

Tags: c#, list, linq

How can I remove objects from a `List<Object>` based on a duplicate ID?  For example:

```
public class Car
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set }
}

Car car1 = new Car()
{
  ID = 123,
  Color = "green",
  Year = "2010"
};

Car car2 = new Car()
{
  ID = 123,
  Color = "blue",
  Year = "2012"
};

Car car3 = new Car()
{
  ID = 153,
  Color = "black",
  Year = "2020"
};

var cars = new List<Car>();
cars.Add(car1);
cars.Add(car2);
cars.Add(car3);
```

If there's duplicate IDs, I need to **remove all but the first one**.  In the above example, I would need to remove only `car2`.  Maybe there's a good `LINQ` way to do this?

---

The recommended SO post **does** answer my question since it's not necessary for me to modify an existing list.  Creating a new list with my requirements as described in the post is sufficient.  :)

Comment: I think that answers my question.  So if I understand correctly, the answer from that post is to not remove from the a list but build a new list based on the property to match.  Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is the LINQ way. Do you need to actually remove the items from an existing list instance? Or is the solution to the duplicate link good enough?

Comment: If you absolutely must adjust an existing list instance, you can use something like this: `int index = 0; HashSet<int> seenCarIds = new HashSet<int>(); while (index < cars.Count) { if (seenCarIds.Add(cars[index].ID)) index++; else cars.RemoveAt(index); }`

Comment: If you're going through a billion items, there may be other more efficient way, and you have to balance time & space efficiencies. But for short, easy-to-follow LINQ solutions, a `GroupBy().ToList()` is the way to go

Comment: MoreLINQ has a `DistinctBy()` method that would work.

`cars.DistinctBy(x => x.ID)`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want, it will filter your cars by ID.

`cars = cars.GroupBy(c => c.Id).Select(c => c.First()).ToList();`